# get historical stock data in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, finance, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I am looking to create a javascript function that can be placed in a .html

I would like to send the function a stock symbol, a starting date, and a ending date.

I would like to have the function return a 2d array where each row is a day of either EOD or OHLC data for the stock requested.

I would like to use Yahoo because Google stock data is going to be phased out.

I have done this in other languages but I new to java script and pretty much lost.

The following code was found on Stack and is the closest I can find, but i don't understand how to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var symbol='goog';
            var callback = function(data) {
                    var price=data.query.results.span[0].content;
                    alert('Stock Price: ' + price);
            };

        var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
        // this is the lovely YQL query (html encoded) which lets us get the stock price:
        // select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog" and xpath='//span[@id="yfs_l10_goog"]'
        var data = "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3D" + symbol + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fspan%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_" + symbol + "%22%5D'&format=json";
        $.getJSON(url, data, callback);
});
```

The following is what I want in javascript but it is in python

```
def get_historical_prices(symbol, start_date, end_date):
"""
Get historical prices for the given ticker symbol.
Date format is 'YYYYMMDD'

Returns a nested list.
"""
url = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&' % symbol + \
      'd=%s&' % str(int(end_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
      'e=%s&' % str(int(end_date[6:8])) + \
      'f=%s&' % str(int(end_date[0:4])) + \
      'g=d&' + \
      'a=%s&' % str(int(start_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
      'b=%s&' % str(int(start_date[6:8])) + \
      'c=%s&' % str(int(start_date[0:4])) + \
      'ignore=.csv'
days = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
data = [day[:-2].split(',') for day in days]
return data
```

Sorry if I am asking too much. As I am new to javascript but I am really interested in learning as much as I can.

Comment: So you want us to transform your code from Python into JavaScript while you just sit-back and relax.

Comment: no, i've been working on this for about a week and even just a pointer of where to start would be helpful. like what would a function call to the top code look like, or is there a javascript version of the urllib.urlopen().

Answer (score 1):

First a little explanation of the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //... lines
});
```

This is a jquery (see the $(document)) event handler (it will be called when the document is ready). The guts of it:

```
        var symbol='goog';
        var callback = function(data) {
                var price=data.query.results.span[0].content;
                alert('Stock Price: ' + price);
        };
```

`callback` is now a closure taking one argument. Being a closure, it takes its context with it, so when it is called it will have access to anything in its scope. Here, it doesn't use anything outside its scope, so it will behave just like a normal function. All it is doing is putting up a dialog with some portion of the data object it was given.

```
    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
    var data = /* stuff */;
```

These just set up the request, which is given to the jquery `getJSON` method:

```
    $.getJSON(url, data, callback);
```

Internally, jquery is sending the `data` request to `url`, and when it receives a response it is calling `callback` with the response, a bit like this pseudocode:

```
 response = queryURL(url,data);
 callback(response);
```

So the structure is to create a query object, and pass it with the target url to jquery to do the hard work for you. You also create a function that expects a single argument, and pass that as well for jquery to call when it gets a response. These are known as callbacks.

To implement your python, just split the url (`http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv`) from the query string (everything afterwards), and use the same structure. Put the logic of what to update (views on the page etc) inside the `callback` function, or even better use that to trigger some update mechanism.

The easiest way to see what is in the json object you get back from yahoo is to use Firebug or the debug tools in Chrome to set a breakpoint inside `callback` and look at its structure. You should be able to see from that structure how to access the individual values from the object yahoo returns.